# How to set a simple invoke test globally?

Tags: cypress

I have this simple piece of cypress code to avoid the flaky test of scrolling

```
cy.get('html').invoke('attr', 'style', 'scroll-behavior: inherit');
```

I want to set it globally and apply it to all of my test. How can i do that?

Comment: What exactly is the issue that gives you flakiness in your tests?

Comment: It doesn't target the proper element on .scrollToView command and i think it's all because scroll-behavior: smooth is applied on the page

Comment: That does not sound right. What is the problem with scrollToView? What is your code?

Answer (score 2):

The `scroll-behavior` attribute isn't inherited, so adding it at a top level won't affect descendants. The `inherit` value must be applied at the child level (the actual scrolling box that controls the scroll action).

See [MDN scroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior#formal_definition)

---

If you are aiming to change the default [Cypress scrollBehavior option](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Actionability) you can do so with a command overwrite, for example:

**cypress/support/e2e.js**

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite(
  'type', 
  function (originalFn, element, text, options = {}) {
    options.scrollBehavior = 'center'
    return originalFn(element, text, options)
  }
)

Cypress.Commands.overwrite(
  'click',
  function (originalFn, subject, positionOrX, y, options = {}) => {
    options.scrollBehavior = 'center'
    return originalFn(subject, positionOrX, y, options)
  }
)

// plus actions - check, clear, dblclick, rightclick, trigger, uncheck
```